# wine installation fails: Depends wine-staging (= 9.0~rc3~jammy-1)

Tags: apt, 22.04, wine, dependencies

I am trying to install wine on Ubuntu 22.04 and following the docs here: https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu

But when reaching this step:

```
sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-staging
```

I get an error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 winehq-staging : Depends: wine-staging (= 9.0~rc3~jammy-1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I also tried `wine` insead of `winehq`:

```
sudo apt install --install-recommends wine-staging
```

But it also doesn't work and outputs this error:

```bash
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine-staging-i386:i386 : Depends: libasound2:i386 (>= 1.0.16) but it is not installable
                          Depends: libglib2.0-0:i386 (>= 2.37.3) but it is not installable
                          Depends: libgphoto2-6:i386 (>= 2.5.10) but it is not installable
                          Depends: libgphoto2-port12:i386 (>= 2.5.10) but it is not installable
                          Depends: libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:i386 (>= 1.0.0) but it is not installable
                          Depends: libgstreamer1.0-0:i386 (>= 1.4.0) but it is not installable
                          Depends: libpcap0.8:i386 (>= 1.10.0) but it is not installable
                          Depends: libpcsclite1:i386 (>= 1.3.3) but it is not installable
                          Depends: libpulse0:i386 (>= 0.99.1) but it is not installable
                          Depends: libsane1:i386 (>= 1.0.27) but it is not installable
                          Depends: libudev1:i386 (>= 183) but it is not installable
                          Depends: libusb-1.0-0:i386 (>= 2:1.0.21) but it is not installable
                          Depends: libwayland-client0:i386 (>= 1.20.0) but it is not installable
                          Depends: libx11-6:i386 but it is not installable
                          Depends: libxext6:i386 but it is not installable
                          Depends: libxkbcommon0:i386 (>= 0.5.0) but it is not installable
                          Depends: libxkbregistry0:i386 (>= 1.0.0) but it is not installable
                          Depends: ocl-icd-libopencl1:i386 but it is not installable or
                                   libopencl1:i386 but it is not installable
                          Depends: ocl-icd-libopencl1:i386 (>= 1.0) but it is not installable or
                                   libopencl-1.2-1:i386 but it is not installable
                          Depends: libasound2-plugins:i386 but it is not installable
                          Depends: libncurses6:i386 but it is not installable or
                                   libncurses5:i386 but it is not installable or
                                   libncurses:i386 but it is not installable
                          Recommends: libcairo2:i386 but it is not installable
                          Recommends: libcups2:i386 but it is not installable
                          Recommends: libdbus-1-3:i386 but it is not installable
                          Recommends: libfontconfig1:i386 but it is not installable
                          Recommends: libfreetype6:i386 but it is not installable
                          Recommends: libglu1-mesa:i386 but it is not installable or
                                      libglu1:i386 but it is not installable
                          Recommends: libgnutls30:i386 but it is not installable or
                                      libgnutls-deb0-28:i386 but it is not installable or
                                      libgnutls26:i386 but it is not installable
                          Recommends: libgssapi-krb5-2:i386 but it is not installable
                          Recommends: libgtk-3-0:i386 but it is not installable
                          Recommends: libkrb5-3:i386 but it is not installable
                          Recommends: libodbc2:i386 but it is not installable or
                                      libodbc1:i386 but it is not installable
                          Recommends: libosmesa6:i386 but it is not installable
                          Recommends: libsdl2-2.0-0:i386 but it is not installable
                          Recommends: libv4l-0:i386 but it is not installable
                          Recommends: libva-drm2:i386 but it is not installable or
                                      libva-drm1:i386 but it is not installable
                          Recommends: libva-x11-2:i386 but it is not installable or
                                      libva-x11-1:i386 but it is not installable
                          Recommends: libva2:i386 but it is not installable or
                                      libva1:i386 but it is not installable
                          Recommends: libxcomposite1:i386 but it is not installable
                          Recommends: libxcursor1:i386 but it is not installable
                          Recommends: libxfixes3:i386 but it is not installable
                          Recommends: libxi6:i386 but it is not installable
                          Recommends: libxinerama1:i386 but it is not installable
                          Recommends: libxrandr2:i386 but it is not installable
                          Recommends: libxrender1:i386 but it is not installable
                          Recommends: libxxf86vm1:i386 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have also checked this question, cause it is similar, but the approach there, installing another package first (`sudo apt install wine-staging-amd64`) doesn't help. It is also not resolved: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73470691/winehq-stable-depends-wine-stable-7-0-0-0focal-1?rq=2
Does anybody know what else can be done?
Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: Are you trying to install wine from some ppa, or the version in the Ubuntu repos? If you are using some ppa, undo all that you have done, and install the version in the Ubuntu repos.

Comment: Its on version 6, super old stuff. I need the newer version. 8 or 9 would be nice

Comment: An old version that works >> a new broken version. But best wishes, hope you get it sorted out.